# Change the icon of clicked navbar dropdown to parent

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Here I was trying to change the clicked dropdown icon to the parent dropdown list. I used the toggle Jquery function but I can't do it properly. Help me out with this. Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
$('.dropdown-item').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').html(($(this).text()));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">


<li class="nav-item mx-auto dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" (click)="toggleClick('cubes', cubes)">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" [ngClass]="{active: cubes}">
    <i class="fa fa-cubes defaultColor dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    </i>
    <div class="dropdown-menu ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-up defaultColor dropdown-item" style="font-size: 30px">
          </i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-down defaultColor dropdown-item" style="font-size: 30px">
          </i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right defaultColor dropdown-item" style="font-size: 30px">
          </i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-left defaultColor dropdown-item" style="font-size: 30px">
          </i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right defaultColor dropdown-item" style="font-size: 30px">
          </i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left defaultColor dropdown-item" style="font-size: 30px">
          </i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add an `onclick` event on each element
- find/parse the current fa-icon from the class string
- find the parent and parse it's fa-icon from the class string
- remove the old and in with the new! :)

```js
function changeParentIcon(element) {
  var self = this;
  var jElement = $(element);
  var newFa = getFirstFaClass(jElement);
  var jParent = jElement.parent().closest('a').children('i').first();
  var oldFa = getFirstFaClass(jParent);
  jParent.removeClass(oldFa);
  jParent.addClass(newFa);
};

function getFirstFaClass(jElement) {
  var css = jElement.attr('class');
  css = css.substr(css.indexOf('fa-'));
  css = css.split(' ')[0];
  return css;
};

$(() => {
  $('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item').on('click', function () {
    changeParentIcon(this);
  });
});
```

```css
.col .defaultColor {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<li class="nav-item mx-auto dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" (click)="toggleClick('cubes', cubes)">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" [ngClass]="{active: cubes}">
    <i class="fa fa-cubes defaultColor dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    </i>
    <div class="dropdown-menu ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-up defaultColor dropdown-item"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-down defaultColor dropdown-item"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right defaultColor dropdown-item"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-left defaultColor dropdown-item"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right defaultColor dropdown-item"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left defaultColor dropdown-item"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

here try this

```
$lastClass = 'fa-cubes';
    $('.dropdown-item').click(function () {
        $rootElement = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.dropdown-toggle')[0];
        $(this.classList).each(function (index, item) {
            if (item.match('(^|\s)(fa\-[^\s]*)'))
            {
                console.log($rootElement);
                if ($($rootElement).hasClass($lastClass)) {
                    $($rootElement).removeClass($lastClass);
                }
                $lastClass = item;
                $($rootElement).addClass(item);

            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: all you need to do is change the class name of the parent list item so you need to locate the icon you want to set and change it with the current classname